# python script to detect LB(loadbalancer)s without instances attached to them

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-elb

I am trying to write python script with boto3 to get output LB names where there are no instances attached
could you please help me.

Comment: Which type of Load Balancer (Classic, ALB, NLB)? Can you show us your code so far?

Comment: Hi John, actually I am looking for below inputs .. 
1. output LB names where there are no instances attached
2. output ordered by oldest LB first
Thanks.

Comment: Which type of Load Balancer (Classic, ALB, NLB)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a Network or Application Load Balancer, this might help,

```
import boto3 

my_client=boto3.client('elbv2', region_name='us-west-2', use_ssl='true')
response = my_client.describe_load_balancers()

for loadbalancer in (response["LoadBalancers"]):
    my_targetgroups=my_client.describe_target_groups(LoadBalancerArn=loadbalancer["LoadBalancerArn"])
    for my_targetgroup in my_targetgroups["TargetGroups"]:
        response_target=my_client.describe_target_health(TargetGroupArn=my_targetgroup["TargetGroupArn"])
        if response_target["TargetHealthDescriptions"]==[]:
            print (loadbalancer["LoadBalancerName"])
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response . I tried to run this but I am getting below error .. Please help me .

Comment: C:\Users\u6018133\Desktop\boto>python Test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 4, in <module>
    response = my_client.describe_load_balancers()
  File "C:\Users\u6018133\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 314, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\u6018133\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 612, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)

Comment: botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the DescribeLoadBalancers operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

Comment: Are you running the code on an Amazon EC2 instance with an assigned role? Or on your own computer with AWS credentials? If the latter, where did the credentials come from and why might they not be valid?

Comment: Hi John,
to get instances details I have run below code it worked fine with proper output of list of instances.

Comment: import boto3
access_key = "*****"
secret_key = "*****"
client = boto3.client('ec2', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,region_name='us-west-2')
ec2_regions = [region['RegionName'] for region in client.describe_regions()['Regions']]

for region in ec2_regions:
    conn = boto3.resource('ec2', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,region_name=region)
    instances = conn.instances.filter()
for instance in instances:
 if instance.state["Name"] == "running":
  print (instance.id, instance.instance_type )

Comment: even it worked for me as well with aws configure command, first  I given details in command line (access key ,secret , region & etc ) .. then I ran the python script with out giving access key and secret key in the code.

Comment: Are you still getting the (InvalidClientTokenId) error? Make sure that the security credentials belong to your account who can operate on the ELB's.

Comment: yes John, still I am getting the error (InvalidClientTokenId) .. I only created instances and loadbalancers in my aws account .. and taken access key & secret key  from that account . Thanks,

Comment: Could you check the cloudtrail logs in your account, it should display any unauthorized access. Plus, in your code where you list the EC2 instances, could you add elbv2 client? To make sure that the same account is utilized for both function calls.